# Operating two wireless cars simultaniously

Tags: wireless

This is my first "serious" electronic project, so I apologize if my question is silly.

I tried to follow [this](https://diyhacking.com/remote-control-car/) tutorial to construct a remotely controlled car.
Moreover, I wanted to make two cars. Each one operated by its remote control
(to make fun with both my boys). I thought that this is what address pins are standing for, so I connected differently the address pins (1-8) of each pair of ht12e-ht12d chips.

However, only one car can be operated at a time. If I turn on both transmiters, this causes a collision (I speculate) and nothing works.

Currently, both cars are operated by the radio trasmitter/reciever of the same frequency (433MHz).
From my search, I found that if I use 433Mhz for one car and 315Mhz for the other, no collision should occur. I'll use this solution if I do not find something better.

My question is why different pinout of address pins doesn't solve the problem. This is what these pins are for (or they are not?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such thing as a silly question. The addressing on the encoder-decoder pair ensures that data is not received by a decoder with a different address from the encoder. A typical application for this would be a "secure" garage door opener where you program the door opener and remote to have the same address.

This will not prevent RF interference from messing up the reception of one or both receivers if you use two transmitters on the same frequency simultaneously. Unfortunately the solution is to split the two radio channels onto different frequencies.